# when I run npm run watch it delete dist folder from root of project

Tags: c#, npm

I have following folder structure of project (this is a open source [bootstrap theme](https://github.com/pikock/bootstrap-magic)):

[image]

In package.json I have following command:

```
"watch": "nodemon -e scss -x \"npm run build\"",
```

When I run **npm run watch** it deletes dist folder.
What is reason behind that. once dist folder is removed, css does not work as it is located within it. How to solve this problem?
Why npm run watch removed dist directory?

**UPDATE:**

After installing grunt watch from [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) and installing grunt locally and globally, now I get this output in my terminal:

```
PS C:\PROJECTS\Bootsrap\bootstrap-magic> grunt watch
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-clean" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-concat" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-connect" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-copy" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-jshint" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-qunit" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-uglify" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-html-validation" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-jekyll" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-less" not found. Is it installed?

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

Comment: Maybe you can use this instead: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch

Comment: What is the purpose of installing this?

Comment: You want to watch files for changes and run a task when they are saved, right?

Comment: Yes. I installed grunt watched after installing grunt locally and globally but it is not working.

I am updating my Question to show what I am getting now in terminal. If you get time you can help. Just one more thing so even I don't run watch even then my project will run only I have to refresh my browser? right?
Or is it for compiling CSS or js file after changes?
Thanks for help @Isma :)

Comment: If you don't care changing Grunt for Gulp (which is now the preferred option for ASP.NET Core) I can post an example of how to watch for files that is working nicely for me...

Comment: @Isma Yes please post an example. I am beginner so it would be nice if you post something basic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `scripts` node in the `package.json` belonging to the package you are referring to:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "npm run build && ./node_modules/.bin/serve ./dist --single",
    "dev": "./node_modules/serve/bin/serve.js",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "watch": "nodemon -e scss -x \"npm run build\"",
    "build": "npm run clean && NODE_ENV=production webpack"
  }
```

The `watch` script runs `build`, which runs`clean`, which removes the `dist` folder using `rimraf`.